# How to repair a twisted Presta valve?

Tags: repair, presta

On one of my old bike, I have a twisted Presta valve:
[image: twisted presta valve]

Unlike [this user](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2388/repairing-presta-valves), I can't put glue on my valve because the air is leaking at the tip of the valve (where it is twisted). So, I want to know if I can change only the tip of my valve or if it is possible to just change the valve without throwing the tube.

Comment: twisted? nothing looks terribly off in this photo besides the rust at the base of the valve. could you describe this a little better? if the very left-most tip is bent, you can just bend it back with your fingers and it should be fine.

Comment: Indeed, the picture don't show it very well but the tip is really twisted and, when I screw it, air is leaking through it. There is no leak from the base of the valve despite the rust.

Comment: twisted? or bent?

Comment: @PaulH I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand the difference between _twisted_ and _bent_ (I'm not a native English speaker).

Comment: Just replace the tube. It's not like they're expensive. Yes, there's an environmental impact but there are _much_ bigger fish to fry in that regard.

Comment: Try rightening down the tip a little harder than normal.  Worst case the thin shaft snaps and you need a new tube anyway.

Comment: @Pierre look up torsional stress vs bending stress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in [this old question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/35083/43557) there exist Presta tubes from which the valve core can be removed; in this case it might be possible to replace the valve core.

However, yours appears to be a single piece valve (non-removable core).

[image: removable vs non-removable core Presta valves]

Since the valve is otherwise trash, I would try gently bending it straight using a pair of pliers.  If it breaks, or doesn't straighten you're no worse off, since you'll have to discard it anyway.

Comment: Yep, use the pliers on the upper threaded portion.  Of course, you'll need a replacement piece salvaged from another tube.

Comment: @DanielRHicks What do you mean by "you'll need a replacement piece salvaged from another tube"? Can I just replace my valve with a piece from another tube?

Comment: @Pierre - Yep, that's what I said.  I said "salvaged" because you'd presumably use the piece from an old tube vs rendering a new tube unusable.

Comment: If I bin a presta tube, I always save the core inner in a little jar assuming its one of the removable ones.